# Delphi can't recognize Russian characters

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, cyrillic

I have an English version of the Windows XP operating system installed on my computer. If I try to use the Russian input language, for example, to give a form a caption that's written in Russian, the only thing I see is those unintelligible symbols that you often see when there is a problem with proper character encoding. Is there a way to make Delphi recognize Russian characters?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any difference in characters between form designer (designtime) and launched application (runtime) ?

Comment: You can try changing default code-page used for programs that do not provide locale info (Control Panel > Regional setting > Advanced)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that by selecting the Russian language for non-Unicode programs. Now Delphi can understand Russian. But I still have a problem. This time it's my MySQL database. It won't process Russian symbols I feed it neither from Delphi nor from the command line. I can see and type Russian, but after inserting stuff into a table it shows lines of question marks instead of Russian text.

Comment: Time to get a Unicode compiler

Comment: Regarding the database, set text fields to have charset win1251 (Cyrillic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change default code-page used for programs that do not provide locale info (Control Panel > Regional setting > Advanced) to your locale (Russian).

As for SQL that is a separate question probably solved by SQL DB settings.

P.S. I would suggest you to move to Unicode version of Delphi (XE) and SQL too.